# How to fix this parameters in function max_2d? conversion from const int to int is the error

Tags: c, arrays, parameters

I'm trying to find the biggest number in a multidimensional array, but Visual Studio has a problem compiling the code successfully.

It has a problem with conversion from `int` to `const int *` when I use parameter `size` as a limitation of `for` loop. It is not able to compare `int i` from `for` loop with parameter `size`. Can anyone help?

Here is the error list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmFly.jpg

```
int max_2d(const int size[], int array[][size]) {

    if (array == NULL) return -1;

    int max = array[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (max < array[i][j]) max = array[i][j];
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int main() {

    int array[2][2] = { {1,2},{0,-3} };
    printf("%d\n", max_2d(2, array));

    return 0;
}
```

In this state i expect an output return max (where max is the biggest number) = 2.

Comment: You are trying to pass `2` as a parameter for `const int size[]` - The number 2 is not an array

Comment: Also why are you posting your errors as an image? They are plain text, you can copy them into the question

Comment: If you remove the `[]` from `const int size[]` in the function prototype, you are then stuck with MSVS probably doesn't recognize C99's "variable length array" (VLA) syntax.  There isn't a good cure for that if you're using the latest version of MSVS and it doesn't support it.  (If you're on an old version, there's a chance a new version will help, but there's a good chance that it won't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the function `const int size`, should be a number not an array, so it should be declare like `const int size`.
Also, this code will work, but its logically incorrect as second index of array (`arr[][]`)
should be known, but here you are passing it as `arr[][size]`.
It is a static memory allocation. The compiler should know the size of all the variables declared at compilation time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first sentence is fine; correct and accurate. The second, not so much — the code uses the C99 variable length array (VLA) notation, and is perfectly legitimate. The size of the second dimension is known; it is `size`.  It is allowed to vary between calls to the function. The "it is static memory allocation" sentence doesn't seem accurate to me. The last sentence ("The compiler should know the size of all the variables declared at compilation time") is more or less accurate, but has the potential to mislead — consider dynamically allocated arrays, VLA (and FAM).